# GDAL Warp Not Producing Proper Mosaic

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdalwarp

I am using the NEDSnapshot of the NHDPlus Dataset as my raster files. They can be found at  https://www.epa.gov/waterdata/nhdplus-california-data-vector-processing-unit-18. I have included an imgur album of my various files if that is helpful https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf31m.jpg. The album contains images of the individual rasters, the vrt, and the mosaic file which is faulty. Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue? I'm new to both python and gdal, so I'm kind of lost as to what I can do to resolve this issue.

My code:

```
import os 
f1 = r'C:\Users\User\Data\NHDPlusCA\NHDPlus18\NEDSnapshot\Ned18a\elev_cm'
f2 = r'C:\Users\User\Data\NHDPlusCA\NHDPlus18\NEDSnapshot\Ned18b\elev_cm'


os.system('gdalbuildvrt mosaic_CA.vrt {} {}'.format(f1, f2))
os.system('gdalwarp mosaic_CA.vrt -co BIGTIFF=YES --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 6000 -wm 500 mosaic_CA.tif')
```

Comment: Can you explain what is "faulty" in the mosaic file?

Comment: if you view the imgur album that I included you can see that the product of the gdalwarp is just random pixels of black and does not represent the combination of the original files.

Comment: Using GDAL from the command line and loading the result into QGIS, I saw the same image, but setting the min and max values to zero and 233703 made the image reasonable. Maybe the NODATA value caused your faulty look.